# Getting weird 404 error when using window.open

Tags: javascript, firefox, exception

I am getting a really strange situation.

I am trying to open a window using window.open

```
myWindow= window.open(myDomain+'/mypath/jsp/loginPage.jsp', 'Window', 'top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',height='+height+', width='+width+', menubar=no, location=0, status=0, scrollbars=no, resizable=no');
```

Now, here is the problem.

When myDomain is localhost:7001, there are no problems (in Firefox at least).  The window opens and displays the correct page.  In IE and Chrome, the window opens for a moment and then closes again before giving me a 404 error in the main window.

That's one problem but I don't have to support anything other than Firefox so I could live with the problem in the other two browsers (I just included that info to give you some info that might help).

The real problem is as follows.

When I substitute my network IP address for localhost so that it is  http://12.34.56.78:7001  The window flashes and disappears and I also get the 404 error in Firefox and I get the following exception in Firebug's log:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMEventTarget.removeEventListener]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/stager/Application%20Data/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/ts2cmib6.default/extensions/%7Bd10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d%7D/modules/ObjectTabs.jsm :: anonymous :: line 343" data: no]
```

[edit]Discovered that disabling AdBlock extension prevents the appearance of the exception.  404 error still an issue though[/edit]

I can't use localhost as the domain because I will eventually have to deploy it to another machine.

Does anyone have any advice to get around this problem?

Thanks in advance.

//Edit
Added http protocol to IP address in post.  I was already using it.

//Edit2
Disabling AdBlock plus stopped exception from appearing in Firebug's log.  404 error still present.

Comment: I just performed a test and discovered that once I deploy, it will be alright (the deployment address doesn't contain an IP address).  But I guess the question still stands (and if it's solved, will help me to develop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an AdBlock Plus exception, so perhaps it's blocking you?

Comment: You're right in that the exception was being caused by AdBlock plus.  After disabling, the exception stopped appearing.  How did you know it was from AdBlock plus?  I'm still getting the 404 error though.

Comment: d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d is AdBlock Plus's GUID.

Comment: I got an error message when I tried; I didn't make a note of it.

Comment: So how a https url can be linked from javascript?

Answer (score 1):

By using URLs with a port, you have to use the protocol before the url ("http://" + myDomain). Firefox is tolerant with that if it is localhost...

Comment: I am using the protocol.  Perhaps that wasn't clear from my post.  I shall edit it now to reflect this.